# How to pass a string to another function

Tags: java, android, class, logging

I try to create a new separate class with 4 properties to make a log over different events, which in my Task creates a new object and assigns different values. so I can more easily sort it since I have different information stored in separate variables in the object.

but I gets a

> unkown class `aLog.id` `aLog.status` `aLog.action` `aLog.time`

and

> methode call expected at  `Log();`

what have I have done wrong?

```
 public class UpdatePro extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;


    String DBcard = cardnumberbox.getText().toString();
    String DBshelf = shelfnumberbox.getText().toString();



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        LStatus aLog = LStatus();
        aLog.id="";
        aLog.status="";
        aLog.action="";
        aLog.time="";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (isSuccess == true) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (DBcard.trim().equals("") || DBshelf.trim().equals(""))
            z = getString(R.string.Invalid_Credentials);
        else {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = getString(R.string.Forbindelses_fejl);
                } else {
                    String itemcard = DBcard;
                    {
                        if (itemcard.substring(0, 1).startsWith("K")) {
                            itemcard = itemcard.substring(1);
                        } else {
                            itemcard = itemcard;//.substring(0));
                        }
                    }
                    String itemshelf = DBshelf;
                    {
                        if (itemshelf.substring(0, 1).startsWith("R")) {
                            itemshelf = "" + itemshelf.substring(1);
                        } else {
                            itemshelf = "" + itemshelf;//.substring(0));
                        }
                    }
                    String doerTicket;
                    doerTicket = setingPreferences.getString("doerTicket", "");
                    String sql =
                            "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +
                                    "DECLARE @upd INT; " +
                                    "EXEC [file].[usp_assignPartToShelf] " +
                                    "@p_ItemNumber=?, " +
                                    "@p_ShelfNumber=?, " +
                                    "@p_UpdatedItems=@upd OUTPUT, " +
                                    "@p_DoerTicket=?;" +
                                    "SELECT @upd AS UpdatedItems;";
                    try (PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                        s.setString(1, itemcard);
                        s.setString(2, itemshelf);
                        s.setString(3, doerTicket);
                        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();  // above T-SQL always returns at least one ResultSet
                        rs.next();
                        if (s.getMoreResults()) {
                            System.out.printf(
                                    "INFO:%n" +
                                            "  A second ResultSet was found.%n" +
                                            "  The previous ResultSet was returned by the stored procedure.%n" +
                                            "  Getting next ResultSet ...%n",
                                    "");
                            rs = s.getResultSet();
                            rs.next();
                            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                            if (rs.getString(1).equals("0")) {
                                z = getString(R.string.Update_succes);
                                isSuccess = true;
                            }

                        }
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                        String sqli = "select ID,ItemNumber,Trashed,Sold from [file].[Item] where [ItemNumber] =?";
                        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqli);
                        preparedStatement.setString(1, itemcard);
                        ResultSet rsS = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                        while (rsS.next()) {
                            String P_id = rsS.getString("ID");
                            String Trashed = rsS.getString("Trashed");
                            String Sold = rsS.getString("Sold");

                            if(Trashed.equals("1.000000")) {
                                //for updating trash
                                CallableStatement cs = null;
                                String queryundo = "{ call [file].[usp_trashItem](?,?,?,?)}  ";
                                cs = con.prepareCall(queryundo);
                                cs.setString(1, P_id); // p_ID
                                cs.setString(2, "U"); //p_Action(U for untrash T for Trash)
                                cs.setInt(3, 1); //p_Quantity
                                cs.setString(4, doerTicket); //p_DoerTicket
                                cs.executeUpdate();
                                z = getString(R.string.untrashed);
                            }
                            else if (Sold.equals("1.000000"))
                            {
                                z = getString(R.string.item_sold);

                            }
                        }
                        con.close();
                        rs.close();
                        rsS.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = getString(R.string.Exceptions) + "L2)";
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", ex);
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

my class

```
package ominidata.ominidata;

import java.util.Date;
public class LStatus {
public String id;
public String action;
public String status;
public Date time;    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Run Time polymorphism is not eligible here, as I can't see any derived child of your LStatus class.
Move object creation in constructor or in preExecute method of AsyncTask.

Use below code create Object

```
LStatus aLog = LStatus();
```

Also update the scope of your variables to public.

```
public class LStatus {
public String id;
public String action;
public String status;
public Date time;
```

Comment: updatet with the whole class so it maybe gives a better overview

Comment: that wasn't the issue

Comment: it fixed some of the issues excpet time is incompatible type reuqire util date found lang string and  = LStatus(); method call expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131273/discussion-between-rahul-kapoor-and-omini-data).

Comment: i still haven't figured that out